# Nested enumeration with enumitem package

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I'm having trouble enumerating with the `enumitem` package.

While the command `\item` produces the enumeration, I cannot seem to do nasty enumeration.

For example:

```
1. .....


i. ii.  iii.
```

etc. I insert the command `\begin{enumerate}  \end{enumerate}` but it does not compile and says that this command is not recognised. The `\usepackage{enumerate}` is loaded in the preamble, as well as the `\usepackage{enumitem}`.

How can I fix that?

Here is what I'm doing:

```
 \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}.]
   \item  ....
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
 \item .....
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

When I do this, well LaTeX says " I do not recognise ... Please read the manual for instructions"

Comment: Can you post an example? and try to load enumitem after enumerate

Comment: Well, the enumitem is loaded after enumerate...

Comment: @touhami I just updated the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don' load both `enumerate` and `enumitem` but only `enumitem`. The `enumitem` package can emulate the functionality of `enumerate` too if you load it with `shortlabels` option. But better is to use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
   \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}.]
   \item  some
\begin{enumerate}[label*=(\alph*)]
 \item some other
 \item some other
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

`enumitem` is more recent and more equipped. With `shortlabels` option it looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
   \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}.]
   \item  some
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
 \item some other
 \item some other
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: :clap: :clap: It works perfectly...

Comment: @Tolaso Thank you. Glad to know it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

this work well for me

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
 %--------------------------------------------------
 \begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}.]
  \item  ....
\begin{enumerate}
 \item .....
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate} 
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm.. well it does not to me.. I don't know what is wrong with that... perhaps my \LaTeX needs an update.